# Line: 4, Column: 23 Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects: Contact

Tags: apex, sobject, constructor

> Line: 4, Column: 23
> Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects: Contact

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>(); // here is Empty List for Contact sObject
System.debug('ConList :='+ ConList);
            
Contact conObj = new Contact(  // here is Error occoured
    FirstName = 'Raman',
    LastName = 'Rathod',
    Phone = '98777777',
    AccountId = accIds  //  here Refrence about contact to Account sObject with look RelationShip.
);
ConList.add(conObj);
System.debug('ConList:='+ ConList);
           
if (!ConList.isEmpty()) {
    insert conObj;
    system.debug('ConList is added:='+ ConList);
}
```

Comment: What is `accIds`?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include the code that defines of `accIds`.

Answer (score 6):

*Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects* means that you've tried to use a custom class using an sObject constructor syntax. It appears that you have a custom class called `Contact` either in the same class (as an inner class) or a top-level class elsewhere in your org. You can easily confirm that this is the problem by changing every instance in your code to use the `Schema` namespace:

```
List<Schema.Contact> conList = new List<Schema.Contact>(); 
Schema.Contact conObj = new Schema.Contact(
  FirstName = 'Raman',
  LastName = 'Rathod',
  Phone = '98777777',
  AccountId = accIds
);
ConList.add(conObj);
insert conObj;
```

Comment: Had a similar issue where someone had created a class called Test. and my test class was not compiling and it made no sense lol

Comment: Had same with StaticResource

Comment: tnx sir  this code solve my problem, and I am glade for this help.